# Running locally, different IIS, what are the names?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-express

I feel there is 3 different IIS and I am not sure what to call them, the differences between them.

1. Building a web project, and ctrl-F5
2. Use Express IIS (guessing it's express IIS, but how is it different than number 1)
3. Setting up the site through IIS Manager and get it running by changing the host file.

thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what are the different names and the differences between those three scenarios

Comment: Ctrl-F5 runs the site on the *configured* webserver, whatever that may be. I think you mean the "built-in webserver". The second is "IIS Express". The third is regular IIS, where a change in the hosts file is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2 are development servers.  1 is called Cassini, or 'built-in web server' for VS.

2 is IIS Express, which is a development server that requires little setup but more closely mimics the behavior of IIS.

3 is IIS.  There's no other name for this, other than the non-abbrevaiated form.

Comment: thanks, I guess when I refer to number 3 I should just call it my local IIS (not to confuse others of the IIS on the server)